# fibonacci of a larger number in java even after using pisano period

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class FibonacciHuge {
       static long get_pisano_period(long m){
    long a=0,b=1,c=(a+b);
    long res=0;
    for(long i=0;i<m*m;i++) {
        c = (a + b) % m;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        if (a == 0 && b == 1) {
            res = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
  }
   static long fun(long n,long m){
    long res=get_pisano_period(m);

    n=n%res;
    long cur=1;
    long pre=0;
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    else if(n==1)
        return 1;
    System.out.println("pre"+n);
    for(long i=0;i<=n-1;i++){
        pre=cur;
        cur=pre+cur;
        System.out.println(pre+" "+cur); //debugging
    }
    return cur%m;
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    long n,m;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=sc.nextLong();
    m=sc.nextLong();
    System.out.println(fun(n,m));
}
}
```

This is the code I have written to find Fn % m using pisano period . But the problem was that while calculating fibonacci number the size of long could not hold the value:

for input n=239 m=1000

```
 \\\ouptut
 144115188075855872 288230376151711744
 -9223372036854775808 0
```

Comment: You may like [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: Is n't it going to work without BigInteger at all

Comment: Of course you may implement multi-precision integer arithmetics by yourself.

Comment: what do you mean by multi-precision integer arithmetics in java

Comment: It is what `java.math.BigInteger` does.